# re-construction of c code: movsx with test instruction

Tags: x86, c, static-analysis

I just started learning about reconstructing C code from assembler instructions.

I have the following piece of assembler code:

```
mov eax dword ptr [ebp+8]
add eax, dword ptr[ebp-4]
movsx ecx, byte ptr [eax]
test ecx, ecx
jne XXXXX
comp dword ptr [ebp-4], ffh
jle XXXX
```

I want to reconstruct the condition of these lines but I have some problems or things I am not sure about:
I re-constructed the following:

Let,`ebp+8= param1` and `ebp-4 = i`

```
if(param1[i]!=’\0’ || i<=0xff){
…
}
```

But I am wondering about this line:

```
movsx ecx, byte ptr [eax]
```

As I understand `movsx` it moves a signed value into a register and sign-extends it with 1. Thus, `ecx` shouble look something like `0xFFFFFF<eax>`. Because only the lower bytes (`byte ptr eax`) of eax are moved and ecx is 1 extended. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Its loading one byte from memory address pointed by value stored inne eax. Ecx = (char)*eax

Comment: and it will become 0xFFFFFFxx only if the bit 7 of [eax] is set, otherwise it will be 0x000000xx.  The point being that the array being read has been defined as a signed char *

Comment: I have one more question: Is the reconstruction to "||" correct?, or should it be a "&&"?

Comment: There is not enough context in the disassembly you gave to say definitively (i.e. where are the jumps going to and what code is being executed for each condition). In general for a null-terminated string/array, it would be `if (array[i] != 0 && i < MAXCOUNT)` -- AND instead of OR

Comment: @cimarron the `jne` jumps right after the `jle`. The `jle` jumps to the function prolog. I know that usually it would be `if (array[i] != 0 && i < MAXCOUNT)`  but to me it looks differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to familiarize yourself with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation. It will only extend the sign bit (msb) into the larger register. So, the msb will be extended into all the additional bits -- sxxxxxxx -> sssssssssssssssssssssssssxxxxxxx

For example, if the byte value pointed to by `eax` was 1 (0b00000001), `ecx` would be 1 (0b00000000000000000000000000000001). Similarly, if it was the most positive number possible in a two's complement byte, 127 (0b01111111), `ecx` would be 127 as well (0b00000000000000000000000001111111).

Where the sign extension is needed is to maintain the value for negative numbers. If the value were -1 (0b11111111), then if you just simply zero-extended into a 32-bit value you would get 255 (0b00000000000000000000000011111111) in `ecx` instead of -1 (0b11111111111111111111111111111111).